# Getting Error related to number format (java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String )

Tags: sql

I am having a query as below

```
select SHIPMENT_COST_SEQNO as SHIPMENT_COST_SEQNO from shipment_cost where shipment_gid = 'A1.53005'
```

which gives me error as 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String '

Though the SHIPMENT_COST_SEQNO  is a 5 digit number but still gives me above error.

This works fine with SQL Interface but when i try execute from application it gives me above error .

Any pointers would be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share more details about your application? Do you try to store the value into a string field?

Comment: The SHIPMENT_COST_SEQNO  is of data type Number. The application is Oracle transportation management (OTM)

Answer (score 1):

seems you need casting as your used in entity sting

```
select cast(SHIPMENT_COST_SEQNO as varchar(50))
 as SHIPMENT_COST_SEQNO from shipment_cost where shipment_gid = 'A1.53005'
```